# Cast integer to numeric, then take log

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift with 2 timestamps, stored as integers.  I want to date the difference of the 2 timestamps, convert from seconds to days, and then take the log of the result.

e.g.:

```
select cast(t1 - t2 as numeric)/86400 as diff from mytable limit 5
```

Which yields:

```
      diff
1 0.000011
2 1.379166
3 1.365104
4 1.357002
5 17.356759
```

However, when I add the log function, the statements fails:

```
select log(cast(t1 - t2 as numeric)/86400) as diff from mytable limit 5
```

yields:

```
Function "log(numeric,numeric)" not supported.
```

This is surprising, because the log function operates just fine on numeric and integer columns in the same table.  Is there some magic I need to do after the cast function, before taking the log?  Or is there a different data type I should be casting to?

Oddly enough, this statement works just fine:

```
select log(cast(1410551376-1310551376 as numeric)/86400) as diff
```

yielding:

```
      diff
1 3.063486
```

/edit: I also get the same error if I remove the explicit cast:

```
select log((t1 - t2)/86400.0) as diff from mytable limit 5
```

Comment: Try casing to double instead.  The message is odd, because Postgres has supported numerics to `log()` for a long time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How do I cast to double?  I thought the "numeric" data type in redshift was double-precision.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ahhh, `cast(... as double precision)` works.  Add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres has supported `numeric` as an argument to `log()` for a long time (and RedShift is based on Postgres).  Perhaps once upon a time, it only allowed double, so this should work:

```
select log(cast(t1 - t2 as double precision)/86400.0) as diff
from mytable
limit 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are defaulting to integer arithmetic, change to force floating point

```
select log(cast(t1 - t2 as numeric)/86400.0) as diff from mytable limit 5
```

also, make sure that `t1` is larger than `t2`

Comment: This yields the same error. In my actual code, I'm including "where t1 > t2".

Comment: I just ran `Select log(cast(99999 - 39992 as numeric)/86400.0) ` and it works just fine. But I am not using postresql, maybe that's your issue?

Comment: The odd thing is, that works for me too.  It's only when you're operating on a column that it fails.

Comment: Are you sure the timestamp columns `t1` and `t2` are typed as integer ?

Comment: Yes.  Furthermore, both timestamp columns can be logged with no problem. It's only when casting as numeric that issues arise.  It turns out I should have been casting as double precision.